# Without programming, get Facebook access token to use graph.facebook.com/me/friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Without using any type of programming language, is it possible to retrieve an active access token so that I can get valid information using https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?

By entering `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends` in the browser, I get the error:

```
{
    "error":
        {
            "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 2500,
            "fbtrace_id": "AT4+yOfsdGN"
        }
}
```

If I use something like this and already logged in to my account, `http://graph.facebook.com/John.Smith?fields=friends.fields(id)` I get the following error:

```
{
    "error":
        {
            "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (John.Smith)",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 803,
            "fbtrace_id": "DLSc6UW7JJS"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I think you won't really be happy until you do some limited programming . . . you can manually append the access token generated by the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). Make sure you check the box to allow access to `user_friends` to give the token permission to get your friends list. 
[image: check box for user_friends]

Your URL will then be `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=LONGGGGGGGACCESSTOKEN`

You should see something like the data pictured below but will need to page through the json response to get all of the results.

[image: facebook api]

Comment: This only displays the total_count of friends: `{ "data": [ ], "summary": { "total_count": 831 } }`

Comment: I've tried to address your comment. I see more than what you indicate.

Comment: Yes, but the data tag is empty. It does not show a single user. And the "summary" tag displays the total_count. And I've seen the same result with two more facebook profiles (obviously logging on before testing).

Comment: I did notice that, when I click on "Get Token", I see a popup with different `User Data Permissions` and `Extended Permissions`. Do I have to select any particular permission for this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah - you have to allow access to user_friends for the token. I added that to the directions.